# Adobe ExtendScript Javascript: Replacing string with a function containing UI elements

Tags: adobe, extendscript

New to coding in general, was wondering if its possible to change a content of a variable and update it to the UI with replace() or change()? I believe its much more harder than that but I can't wrap my head around it.

```
(function(thisObj) {

    scriptBuildUI(thisObj)

    function scriptBuildUI(thisObj) {
        var win = (thisObj instanceof Panel) ? thisObj : new Window("palette", "replaceTest", undefined, 0);
        win.alignChildren = ['center','top'];

    var myTab = win.add("panel", undefined); 
        var replacebutton = myTab.add("button",undefined,"Replace");
        var myTab2 = "x";
        replacebutton.onClick = function(){ myTab2.replace("x",function(){hO()}) };

        function hO() {myTab.add("button", undefined,"Retgf")};

        win.onResizing = win.onResize = function() {
            this.layout.resize();
        };

        win instanceof Window
            ? (win.center(), win.show()) : (win.layout.layout(true), win.layout.resize());
    }


})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you try to do here. *myTab2* is a string variable and *.replace()* is a string function there. It returns a *string*. So you are trying to replace the "x" with the content of the function? To what end?
Also, the way i see it, that would just add another button to *myTab*.

If you could tell me what you try to do, maybe we can find a work-around.

Edit: To just assign your function to myTab2, you can directly do that. And if you want changes to your UI, i think you need to run *win.layout.layout(true);* to make them vissible. The folowing code adds a button to your tab every time it's clicked.

```js
    (function(thisObj) {

        scriptBuildUI(thisObj)

        function scriptBuildUI(thisObj) {
            var win = (thisObj instanceof Panel) ? thisObj : new Window("palette", "replaceTest", undefined, 0);
            win.alignChildren = ['center','top'];

            var myTab = win.add("panel", undefined);
            var replacebutton = myTab.add("button",undefined,"Replace");
            var myTab2 = "x";
            replacebutton.onClick = function(){ myTab2=hO() };

            function hO() {
                myTab.add("button", undefined,"Retgf");
                win.layout.layout(true);
            };

            win.onResizing = win.onResize = function() {
                this.layout.resize();
            };

            win instanceof Window
            ? (win.center(), win.show()) : (win.layout.layout(true), win.layout.resize());
        }
    })(this);
```